# Best column type in mysql for decimal time

Tags: mysql

I have a timesheet application where people put eg. 3.5 hours worked in a day.

Sometimes someone might put 1.25 I guess.

I stored as float but am now having issues when I retrieve data... Should I have used decimal to 2 or 3 points?.

Comment: You could store the number of minutes, eg 1.25 hours == 90 minutes. So everything is in int format which is probably better for additions

Comment: Last system I used that took time converted everything to minutes, you put in 3.5 hours it recorded it as 210 minutes. Storing the number of minutes as an integer prevented rounding errors, even for thirds or 10ths of an hour.

Comment: Thanks I really love your minutes idea, that's brilliant coz then I can use int

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this.

If you want to have uniformity in the entries, I'd suggest using a "Fixed-Point Type" value (see more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)).  This would mean that 3.5 hours should always be saved as 3.50.

The other option is to convert all your values to integer values (see more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)), and in your application layer, convert the values back to "readable" format.  For example, you would store 1.25 hours as 125, and in your application layer, divide by 100, therefore getting 1.25.  This method is more useful for currency management/calculation applications where a specific level of precision is necessary.

Floats allow for floating decimal point precision, so there is no restriction on uniformity of precision for decimal values...

For your purposes, I'd recommend fixed-point type unless there's complexity that you didn't mention.

Hope that helps.